# What is a raid "sub-system"?

Tags: raid

I've been looking at various server raid systems on newegg and was wondering what it means by "Sub-System" for things like [Tekram T08 8 Bay Desktop Tower RAID Sub-System](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816208016).

What is a "sub-system"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subsystem is [defined](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=vzl&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=define%3Asubsystem&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) as "A group of related components that are part of a larger system"

It means that it is not an independent storage solution like a NAS or SAN, but needs to be connected to a PC or server to function. It is a a system in the sense that the disk array and controller are fully contained in the enclosure, but the "sub" part comes from the fact that it cannot function on its own.